# PDE Cauchy problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the following Cauchy problem.

$u_t  -  \dfrac{1}{2} (  u_x )^2 = 0$ in $t>0$ , $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

$u(x,0)= \dfrac{x^2}{2} $ on $t=0 $ , $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A hint is to differentiate with respect to $x$, then make a variable substitution. Then solve using method of characteristics.

Comment: @Mattos Thank you for your hint.I am learning all this on my own without any teacher and internet is the only help.I have solved other type of Cauchy problem but not this one.Therefore I have no idea where to begin with.

Comment: Would you like me to make a proper post with that guides you through the problem or have you managed it already?

Comment: @Mattos I haven't yet got the answer. Answer: $u(x,t)=\dfrac{-x^2}{2(t-1)}$.

Comment: I added a post below. Follow those steps and see how you go. Feel free to comment again if you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some guidelines on how to solve the problem. Most of the things I explain are tricks which come with experience.

1. Differentiate your PDE with respect to x. Remember that when differentiating the $(u_x)^{2}$ term you need to use [implicit differentiation](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/ImplicitDiff.html).
2. Next make a substitution $v = u_{x}$ to arrive at the [Inviscid Burgers Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation) in the variable v.
3. Solve the IBE for $v$ using the [Method of Characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).
4. Change back from $v$ to $u_{x}$
5. Integrate to get $u$

If you are unfamiliar with any of the above steps, just comment below and I'll try and answer as best I can. Also, if you are unsure of how to use the MOC, just go to youtube and search for 'Method of Characteristics Dr. Chris Tisdell', he has some very good lectures uploaded.

Comment: what will happen to $u_t$  when I differentiate it w.r.t $x$?

Comment: @zafran $u_t$ still depends on $x$, so you get $u_{tx}-u_xu_{xx}=0$ (using the chain rule on the second term).

Comment: @zafran

$$\partial_{x} (u_{t}) = u_{t x} = \partial_{t} (u_{x})$$

Comment: I mean what to do with $u_{tx}$ ?

Comment: @zafran You're now up to step 2 from the guidelines, and use the fact that

$$u_{t x} = \partial_{t} (u_{x})$$

Comment: @Mattos Ah I couldn't see that.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks.You are a genius.I got the same answer with your hints.